# Averaging geo data in 2D with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Super Users,

I have a multi index dataframe, that looks like this:

```
                                                        DATA
DATETIME   PLATFORM OBTYPE LONGITUDE LATITUDE PRESSURE
2014-12-01 GPSRO    ba      164.87   -16.22   0.2086   -1.080487
                           -99.87     51.67   433.9650  9.404006
                           -99.84     51.66   447.1593  8.621209
                           -99.82     51.65   460.5582  9.060276
                           -99.78     51.63   474.2856  4.033578
                           -99.75     51.62   488.2451 -3.564176
                           -99.72     51.61   502.6438  2.418914
                           -99.71     51.60   517.6590  9.504872
                           -99.68     51.59   533.0165  2.074352
                           -99.63     51.57   548.5572  1.692488
                           -99.61     51.56   564.5204  1.287064
                           -99.58     51.55   581.1121  2.060976
...                                                          ...
                           -98.81     51.25   885.3300  1.078527
                           -98.79     51.24   911.0555 -6.613088
                           -98.66     51.20   936.2419  4.369489
                           -98.61     51.18   962.0027  4.806168
                           -98.60     51.17   989.4301 -9.383631
```

The LATITUDE column has values from -90 to +90
The LONGITUDE column has values from 0 to 360
The DATA column is the observed value at the observed latitude and longitude

I want to create a new DataFrame that contains a 1-deg by 1-deg box average of the DATA
The new DataFrame will look something like this:

```
                                                            DATA
DATETIME   PLATFORM OBTYPE LONGITUDE LATITUDE PRESSURE
2014-12-01 GPSRO    ba        0.0    -89.50   0.2086   -1.080487
                                     -88.50   474.2856  4.033578
                                     -87.50   488.2451 -3.564176
...                                                          ...
                              1.0    -89.50   0.2086   -1.080487
                                     -88.50   474.2856  4.033578
                                     -87.50   488.2451 -3.564176
...                                                          ...
```

so on and so forth.

What is the best and efficient way to do this in pandas?

Thanks

Comment: it's not quite clear how did you get new values for `LONGITUDE` and `LATITUDE` columns. What is the algorithm?

Comment: It is just data. It can come from anywhere. GPS location, for eg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple steps to do that:

1. Create your bins, here I am using the `np.floor` function because it does what you want and keeps things simple. Also has the advantage to be vectorized, so the performance should be decent and stable.
2. Aggregate over these bins by taking the average. For that, `pandas` has the nice `groupby` function ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [more on the subject](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)).

Here is what I would do (disclaimer: I haven't tested it, so it might need a couple tweaks):

```
import numpy as np

no_index_df = df.reset_index()
no_index_df['LONGITUDE'] = no_index_df['LONGITUDE'].apply(lambda x: [e for e in range(0, 361, longitude_bin) if e <= x][-1])
no_index_df['LATITUDE'] = no_index_df['LATITUDE'].apply(lambda x: [e for e in range(-90, 91, latitude_bin) if e <= x][-1])

avg_data = no_index_data.groupby(
    ['DATETIME', 'PLATFORM', 'OBTYPE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE', 'PRESSURE']
).mean()
```

The only problem of this method is that you might have several rows for a same `(longitude, latitude)` pair, because of the aggregation over `'PRESSURE'`. You could get it out of the `groupby` list and it would be averaged as well.

EDIT: I changed step 1 (create the bins) to let you use any interval.

Comment: This works. However, the binning you do is simply truncating the lat/lons. I want to test with different binning intervals. 1,2,5 degree bins. The get rid of the pressure aggregation, I suppose one could simply drop the pressure column altogether, since all pressure levels are accumulated for a bin.

Comment: The edit actual fails for the longitude. An IndexError emerges: 

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Are you sure you're longitudes are in [0, 360]? Because if they are, you shouldn't have an error.

Comment: I was about to write back. My longitude limits are [-180,180]. Fixing that makes it work. Thanks. This is exactly what I want. I will do the same for PRESSURE or HEIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the accepted answer: the lambda function is very slow. As soon as you have a few hundred thousand of rows and a few dozen bins, it can take several minutes to compute. I found the following to be much faster, only taking a couple of seconds instead:

```
import numpy as np

def find_nearest(value, array):
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

N_bins_long = 360
N_bins_lat = 180

longbins = np.linspace(df.LONGITUDE.min(), df.LONGITUDE.max(), N_bins_long)
latbins = np.linspace(df.LATITUDE.min(), df.LATITUDE.max(), N_bins_lat)

no_index_df = df.reset_index()
no_index_data.['LONGITUDE'] = no_index_data.['LONGITUDE'].apply(find_nearest, array = longbins)
no_index_data.['LATITUDE'] = no_index_data.['LATITUDE'].apply(find_nearest, array = latbins)

avg_data = no_index_data.groupby(
    ['DATETIME', 'PLATFORM', 'OBTYPE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE', 'PRESSURE']
).mean()
```